Is there a difference between always discarding a returned Task and making the method async void?
I was trying to make a view model where some properties are loaded from a background thread.
For this task, I found this old MSDN article by Stephen Cleary on NotifyTaskCompletion<T>. The code listing "Figure 4" in the section A Better Approach looks like this:
public sealed class NotifyTaskCompletion<TResult> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public NotifyTaskCompletion(Task<TResult> task)
    {
        Task = task;
        if (!task.IsCompleted) {
            var _ = WatchTaskAsync(task);
        }
    }

    private async Task WatchTaskAsync(Task task) {
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}

Now I wonder - if I have a method like WatchTaskAsync that I never want to await (not awaiting that task is essentially the purpose of this whole class), is there a difference to making the method async void in the first place?
I am aware of the difference between await and discard, but in this specific context, where the method is only ever called in a scenario where I don't want to await its completion, creating that Task object just to discard it every time makes no sense, does it?

The compiler will generate a Task for you under the hood regardless of the choice here. So there is no performance benefit, while you write a dangerous code. The real problem is that both choices are bad - you should not discard the Task, but store it somewhere and monitor it. And maybe catch and react to potential exceptions. You should eventually await it, IMO this design is not good.

@freakish As I said, the point of this class is specifically that the discarded task is not relevant, doesn't need monitoring, will never throw, etc. The task that you pass in is the relevant thing, and that is monitored and handled properly.

@Fildor Yes, I edited the code snippet to make that more obvious :)

If you want a "fire and forget" task it can be useful to clearly show that that is the intended behavior. And that you did not use "async void" due to not knowing better.

Discarding a Task is called fire-and-forget.
Launching an async void operation is called fire-and-crash.
The difference appears in case of an error. The exception of the fired-and-forgotten Task will never be emerged. It will remain under the radar forever. The exception of the async void operation will be rethrown on the captured SynchronizationContext, and all known SynchronizationContexts propagate their exceptions loudly, popping up message boxes etc. In case there is no SynchronizationContext, like in a console application, the exception is rethrown on the ThreadPool, causing the process to crash a few milliseconds after the error¹.
In case you have a Task, and you want it to be treated as async void, the easiest thing to do is to await it on the ThreadPool:
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async _ => await task);

The ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method doesn't understand async delegates, so this async delegate is actually async void. And since the ThreadPool has no synchronization context for the async void to capture, you'll get crashing behavior.
¹ Which sounds bad, but it's arguably better than the alternative. It's better to get a crash with an error message, than to get a non-responsive application that hangs spontaneously without giving any feedback.

Assigning an exception to a Task is enough to consider it handled, even if that task is garbage collected without ever being looked at? I knew that an exception thrown inside async void crashes your app, but I didn't know that doesn't happen for discarded async Task returns.

@LWChris the .NET Framework 4.0 was the only .NET version where a faulted Task with unobserved exception would crash the process. See the documentation of the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event for details. Even then the crash was not instantaneous. The process crashed when the faulted Task was garbage collected, which is a non-deterministic event. It was a terrible design decision, and thankfully they changed it in the very next .NET release.
